# pulling information from xml but wont display

Tags: android, xml

Nothing is getting written to the TextView screen.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but this is my following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <news> 
  <article title="TITLE HERE" link="*.php?showtopic=118" date="DATE HERE"></article> 
 </news>
```

JAVA CODE:

```
try {
    //open an URL connection make GET to the server and
    URL url = new URL("http://.../m_news.xml");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    //DocumentBuilderFactory, DocumentBuilder are used for
    //xml parsing
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    //using db (Document Builder) parse xml data and assign
    //it to Element
    Document document = db.parse(is);
    Element element = document.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList nodeList = element.getElementsByTagName("news");
    NodeList nodeList2 = element.getElementsByTagName("article");

        if (nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.getLength(); i++) {
                Element entry = (Element) nodeList.item(0); 

                Element _rowE = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("article").item(i);  
                Node _rowTITLE = _rowE.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title");
                Node _rowLINK = _rowE.getAttributes().getNamedItem("link");

                TextView textview = new TextView(this);
                textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                String text = "<a href='"+_rowLINK.getNodeValue()+"'>"+_rowTITLE.getNodeValue()+"</a>";
                textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                setContentView(textview);
            }
        }    
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did you try just setting the text, instead of html.fromHtml?

Comment: If you're doing all that in the UI thread, that's really bad...

Comment: Hadn't heard that term.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating `TextView`s and calling `setContentView()` with each of them... this is never going to work. At the very least you need to give some layout instructions (i.e. call `setLayoutParams` on each `TextView`) but I'm not even sure that will work without some kind of container object.

Try this. Create a simple layout called news.xml which has this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/newsItems"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
/>
```

Then change your code to include the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.news);
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.newsItems);
...
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.getLength(); i++) {
    ...
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT));
    ...
    textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    linearLayout.addView(textview);
}
```